# Filtering objects from NSMutableArray with NSInteger attribute bigger than k

Tags: objective-c, filter, nsmutablearray

I have searched but all the questions talk about sorting NSStrings.

I have a NSMutableArray with objects (`myvector`) which have an attribute `NSDecimalNumber` called `fitness`.

I want to filter all the object which attribute fitness is equal or grater than a 'k' value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `NSPredicate`. I just assumed the value of k to be 2.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fitness>=2.0"];
NSArray *arr = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Shanti's answer which is appropriate in your case, you can also do something like

```
NSIndexSet* indexSet = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[(YourObjectClass*)obj fitness] doubleValue] > k;
}];

NSArray* filteredArray = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```

which is somewhat more flexible in some cases.